# Click event fires twice, but only on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, backbone.js, touch

```
$('.classy').on('click', 'button', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
})
```

-

```
<div class='classy'>
    <button> - </button>
</div>
```

Any reason why this would fire twice on a touch device? It works perfectly with normal mouse events.

note: I've also tried .bind .live just to make sure, same problem.

Comment: Do you have any other events attached to that DOM element?

Comment: Some markup would help, or better yet a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: No I don't think so, plus it's the same event firing both time, logging clicked.

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6ZZU2/1/ with your example, it fires one on iPhone4 (Safari Mobile) and on Firefox (PC); have you got other events attached?

Comment: No I don't have any other events binded. It does nothing if I unbind. I'm using backbone.js. The problem doesn't exist with mouse events on click. How could I go about trouble shooting this?

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle with backbone and underscore included http://jsfiddle.net/6ZZU2/2/; button fires one. Can you post more code?

Comment: I figured out that a scrolling lib was hijacking all click events and processing them on it's own terms. When two scroll divs were layered they both hijacked the click and processed it without talking to one another.

Comment: to debug you could try binding directly to the button instead of delegating the click via jquery's new .on(). It's possible there is a bug in jquery when trapping events on delegated button clicks..

Comment: I'm trying to track this down too. In my app I think it has something to do with the click first capturing the touch events, then again for mouse events. I'm not using jQuery, just good old onClick=""

Answer (score -1):

Try passing the event and then invoking preventDefault().

```
$('.classy').on('click', 'button', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log('clicked');
})
```